# Oracle Integration Cloud Notification email is not sending

Tags: oracle, rest, email, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Im trying to run this sample in Oracle Integration Cloud.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/integrations-user/running-hello-world-sample.html

But im having this error in the audit trail.

```
Message processed successfully for Trigger helloWorld.
Message processed successfully for Logger logIncoming.
Message processed successfully for Assignment assignSecondaryTracking.
**Error processing message in Notification sendMail.**
Message processed successfully for Reply getMail.
```

Is there an additional configuration that I need to do?

And in case this was solved, anyone knows how to send this notifications with attachment. Thanks

Comment: FYI a lot of issues with configuring send notifications in your integrations has been resolved in 18.4.5. I believe it is still in pre release but you can open an SR to have the patch show in your PSM console. I experienced no issues going from 18.3.5 to 18.4.5 directly

Answer (score 0):

Before I get started I want to encourage you to read the section entitled *StackOverflow Best Practices* located at the bottom of this post

## Recommendation

There are a few issues that could be causing this.  Firstly, in earlier versions of 18.2 the notification action was not working at all.  Additionally, I have experience issues using french characters, html, and other text inside the body of the message.

Since your integration continued to getMail I do not believe there is an issue in your xpath mapping in the notification action.  Instead, I would verify the following.

1. Firstly, verify that inside the identity console (not in OIC, in Oracle Clouds identity console) you need to verify an email is set up there.  In the side bar of your identity console you should see "Settings" - > "Notifications".  Verify you have an email address there and it is verified.

   > To verify an email address you must receive an email to postmaster@whateverdomianisyours.com
   >   and follow the directions
2. After you verified the email it should now show it with a "green" status.  Then, underneath make sure your have the necessary email configurations turned on.
3. If that doesn't work navigate to the administrative console in the processes component of OIC and verify that you have turned on your email service.  You can do this by going to "Administrator" -> "Services" -> "Email Service".

## Issue Persisting?

If the issue persists please turn on tracing and record the payload.  Then run the integration, post the audit payload results, and upload the underline code in your IAR integration.

## StackOverflow Best Practices

In the future I would recommend that you do the following.

1. Post the your major and minor version as showing below

   > You can find this by clicking "About" in the upper right hand corner of your integration dashboard page
2. Enable tracing when activating an integration and post your payload (see image below)
3. Outline your past troubleshooting steps
4. Export your IAR project and post the underline XML, as well as any pertinent JavaScript functions, custom Java XPath tags, etc.

Tracing / Payload

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*We can now send attachments using the notification activity in Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC) by enabling the featuring flag --> **oic.ics.console.notification-attachment**

For more info, please follow the below oracle blog:
https://blogs.oracle.com/integration/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-in-oic*